# Word substitution from offset x to y in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6, regexp-replace

I need to replace a word from a sentence. For example:

```
Programming makes my eyes grow tired. Eyes are cool.
```

I need to replace the first occurrence of the word "eyes" with the word "brain" and the second occurrence of the word "Eyes" with the word "Ears". I want to use the offset of the first word Eyes and the offset of the second word Eyes.

My code:

```
suggestion.addEventListener('click', function() {

    let offsetStart = parseInt(value[i]['offset']),
        offsetEnd = parseInt(value[i]['offset']) + parseInt(value[i]['word'].length);

    // VALUES: Programming makes my eyes grow tired. Eyes are cool.
    const textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value;
    // REPLACED VALUE: Programming makes my brain grow tired. Ears are cool.

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = 'Programming makes my eyes grow tired. Eyes are cool.';
let res = str.replace(/^(.*?)eyes(.*?)eyes/i, 
            (_, g1, g2) => g1 + 'brain' + g2 + 'Ears');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be shortened to:

```js
const input = 'Programming makes my eyes grow tired. Eyes are cool.';
let result = input.replace(/\b(eyes)\b(.*?)\b(eyes)\b/i, 'brain$2Ears');
console.log(result);
```

Explanation of regex:

- `\b(eyes)\b` -- capture group 1: literal `eyes` with word boundaries (this avoids false positives like `eyesore`
- `(.*?)` -- capture group 2: non-greedy scan to:
- `\b(eyes)\b` -- capture group 3: literal `eyes`

***Learn more about regex:*** https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex